# How to make a slide button in flutter? Not a switch button

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter-animation

How can I make a slide button in Flutter (instead of a switch button)?

[image: Image - Slide Button in Flutter]

Comment: You can make a Stack and take help of AnimatedPositioned()  to move the blue part from left to right

Answer (score 0):

In flutter does not have that button. You will need to do by yourself.
In this repo https://github.com/davidsdearaujo/switcher_login the button login is very similtar what are you looking for.